# how to restart app in android oreo and higher version devices?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I can restart app in devices which are below android oreo, My question is that, how  I can perform the restart in oreo and higher version devices, using Kotlin or Java ??

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
    val mPendingIntentId = 1000
    val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, mPendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    val mgr = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent)
    System.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your Activity call `recreate();` This will cause the activity to be recreated in a new instance.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

System.exit(0) is not a best approach as you can't expect status of current threads running under your app, it can lead to corrupted file issue. Try this piece:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
```